# Keep lines drawing from same point after visible chart region changes

Tags: pine-script

My pine script shows multiple lines (in a separate pane) which have the same start y-coordinate:

[image]

Is there a way to listen for visible-chart-area changes, so that the chart can be recalculated so that again all top-left lines start at the same point?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Pine currently does not support interaction with the chart pane, so I'm afraid what you're trying to do is not possible in Pine at the moment.